# Criteria for completing the Orbit contract

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I've had a kerbal in a decaying orbit for some time now (I lose about a meter to my apoapsis every 3 seconds), with an apopsis of ~80km and periapsis of ~67 km. I've made a few rotations around Kerbal, but my 'Achieve orbit' contract has not gained a check-mark. My orbit has since decayed, as seen below, and I expect I will not complete the contract despite several successful rotations around Kerbal.

[image]

Am I failing to meet some hidden criteria? What are the exact criteria needed to complete this contract?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After re-reading the contract from the Contracts screen, I see that there is a minimum periapsis of 70 km. So close!

Comment: Yep, if your periapsis isn't above 70km (for Kerbin), your orbit isn't stable, at least according to the game. Also, I think you need to stage in order for the contract to be fulfilled.